# EF Core - No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: entity-framework-6, .net-core

I am new to EF Core 1.0. Getting below error when I run below command during DB migration

Command

```
 migrations add ApplicationUserIsActive -c ApplicationDbContext
```

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been
>   configured  for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by
>   overriding the  DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using
>   AddDbContext on the application  service provider. If AddDbContext is
>   used, then also ensure that your  DbContext type accepts a
>   DbContextOptions object in its  constructor and passes it to
>   the base constructor for DbContext.

The StartUp.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
options.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=employee;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;")
       .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider));

        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<EmplooyeeDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
options.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=employee;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;")
       .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider));

        services.AddTransient<IUserContext, SeedUserContext>();
    }

}
```

**.csproj file**

```
 <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.0.0">
  <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations" Version="1.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
```

However when I execute the migration command for other DBContext i.e. "**EmplooyeeDbContext**" the migration commend works fine.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What does your .csproj file look like?  Do you have a package reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` ?

Comment: yes, it contains the required reference.

Comment: Did you try to call `ApplicationDbContext` once and after that add two `AddDbContext`? Seems like you're overriding one against another.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It was due to the default constructor of "**ApplicationDbContext**" which was causing the issue. After removing the default constructor for "**ApplicationDbContext**" it all started working fine.

Thanks for all your support.

Comment: So simple and so easily missed as its generated by the package manager command line!

Comment: if we remove default contructor then how we can create new object.

Comment: @ChetanChaudhari using Dependency Injection

Comment: Thanks! I spent hours what a silly thing to happen. Since the weird thing happens, can anyone explain why that is the case? what is the rationale behind it?